# How to show value inside the graph bars in amcharts

Tags: php, jquery, amcharts

I am using amcharts library for making graphs. i make column chart in which i will show value inside the graph. but some of the value are not properly adjust inside the bars in graphs. here is the screen shot of graph.

[image]

As you can see above some values are perfectly show inside the bars but some values are out of the bars.
Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks. Here is the Graph code.

```
   <script>

          var chart8;

        var chartData8 = [

   <?php foreach ($result as $val) { 
   ?>
            {


                "Division": '<?php echo $val['DIVISION_NAME'] ?>',
                 "Target": '<?php echo number_format($val['TARGET_QTY']/1000000,2) ?>',
                 "Actual": '<?php echo number_format($val['DISPATCH_QTY']/1000000, 2) ?>',
                 "Difference": '<?php echo number_format($val['BALANCE_QTY']/1000000, 2) ?>'                    

    },
<?php } ?>

        ];


        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIAL CHART
            chart8 = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart8.dataProvider = chartData8;
            chart8.categoryField = "Division";
            chart8.startDuration = 1;
            chart8.depth3D = 50;
             chart8.angle = 45;
            chart8.marginRight = 80;
    chart8.plotAreaBorderColor = "#DADADA";
           // chart3.plotAreaBorderColor = "#DADADA";
            chart8.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0;
    //chart8.responsive.enabled = true;
            // this single line makes the chart a bar chart
            //chart3.rotate = true;

            // AXES
            // Category
            var categoryAxis = chart8.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
            categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.color =  '';

            // Value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.5;
            tickLength: 0;
    valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    valueAxis.maximum = 3.5;
            valueAxis.position = "bottom";
    valueAxis.color =  '';
            chart8.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPHS

            // second graph
            var graph9 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph9.type = "column";
            /*graph2.title = "PKR Value";*/
            graph9.valueField = "Target";
            graph9.balloonText = "Target:[[value]]";
            graph9.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph9.fillColors = ["#FFD244"];
            graph9.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph9.labelText =  '[[value]]';
    graph9.labelRotation = 90;
    graph9.labelPosition = 'right'; // change to inside
    graph9.color =  '#000';
    graph9.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph9);
           // first graph

            var graph8 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph8.type = "column";

            graph8.valueField = "Actual";
            graph8.balloonText = "Actual:[[value]]";
            graph8.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph8.fillColors = ["#ee8989"]; 
            graph8.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph8.labelText =  '[[value]]';
    graph8.labelRotation = 90;
    graph8.labelPosition = 'right'; // change to inside
    graph8.marginRight = 10;
    graph8.color =  '#000';
    graph8.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph8);

     var graph10 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph10.type = "column";
    graph10.valueField = "Difference";
            graph10.balloonText = "Difference:[[value]]";
            graph10.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph10.fillColors = ["#6acb5f"]; 
    graph10.labelText =  '[[value]]';
    graph10.labelRotation = 90;
    graph10.labelPosition = 'right';
     graph10.marginRight = 10;
            graph10.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph10.color =  '#000';
    graph10.labelColorField =  '#FFFFFF';
            chart8.addGraph(graph10);

            // LEGEND
            var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
           // chart2.addLegend(legend);

            chart8.creditsPosition = "top-right";
            // WRITE
            chart8.write("dailyprod");
        });
    </script>
```

Please Help me to Solve this thing.